# Error while inserting image into access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, insert, ms-access-2007

I am trying to insert an image into my MS Access 2007 database. The datatype I chose is "OLEObject" and Fieldname as "Image".
I tried the following code which executes when a button is pressed:

```
Private Sub ButtonPress()

    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim MemStream As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim DataPic_Update As Byte()
    Dim strImage As String

    If Not IsNothing(PictureBox1.Image) Then

        PictureBox1.Image.Save(MemStream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
        DataPic_Update = MemStream.GetBuffer
        MemStream.Read(DataPic_Update, 0, MemStream.Length)
        strImage = "?"
        MemStream.Close()

    Else
        DataPic_Update = Nothing
        strImage = "NULL"
    End If

    con.Open()

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Inventory([Image])" + "VALUES(@Image)"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", OleDbType.Binary).Value = DataPic_Update
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

While executing the command "ExecuteNonQuery", I am getting following Error:

"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

I am not able to solve this error. Can someone please help me with any suggestions or modifications required in my existing code?
I want to insert the image and then retrieve from the access database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to concatenate the cmd.CommandText, there is a space missing between "([Image])" and "VALUES(@Image)" so the resulting query is:

"INSERT INTO Inventory([Image])VALUES(@Image)"

Instead of

"INSERT INTO Inventory([Image]) VALUES(@Image)"

There is no need for the brackets surrounding "Image" as the field does not contain a space nor is a reserved keyword.

Check that you have all the dependencies needed to embed binary files in access. This dependencies are sometimes not very clear, per instance I remember that in Windows XP with Access XP you needed to install Paintbrush to be able to acomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use the below code which I test on Access Database:

```
Private Function ReadFile(sPath As String) As Byte()
    'Initialize byte array with a null value initially.
    Dim data As Byte() = Nothing

    'Use FileInfo object to get file size.
    Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(sPath)
    Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
    'Open FileStream to read file
    Dim fStream As New FileStream(sPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    'Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array.
    Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
    'When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file.
    'In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes.
    data = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))
    fStream.Close()
    fStream.Dispose()
    Return data
End Function
```

And code to Save Image to MS Access Database

```
 Dim logo() As Byte = ReadFile("E:\logo.jpg")
    ' Update(23373, logo)
    Try
        Dim CN As New OleDbConnection(Str_Conn)
        CN.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update TblInventory Set Image=@img Where Image_ID=@id", CN)
        cmd.Connection = CN

        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@finger", DirectCast(logo, Object)))

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 51384)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        CN.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error Occured while Registering Finger Prints, Try Again" + ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try
```

Important Note: You must pass parameters in the Same Sequence you mentioned in Query.